# Running out of memory when deploying Xamarin Forms Android app

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The problem I am having is that when I try to run my application onto my android emulator I get the error of: There is not enough storage space on the device to store package:/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk. Free up some space and try again.

The emulator runs fine, its when I try and deploy the app that it gives me the message. I know that it has something to do with space on the enumlator. I have tried to see what I could find on here but none of it seems to work in this case. I have looked up some of the same questions on here but so far they have not been effective. I have tried to uninstall apps, clear data, change the size of the sd card and ram, also I have tried to make the java heap bigger. At this point I do not know where to go from here.

I am pretty much asking what can I do from here to try and fix this issue? I will provide pictures of the setting and the exact output messages since there where no error messages technically. I am using visual studio enterprise 2017 and using Xamarin Forms.

**Pictures here:**

- [This is a picture of the settings for the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjVH6.png)
- [This is the second picture of the settings for the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBN6r.png)
- [This is the picture of the Output window where I get the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2uPD.png)

Comment: You asked the same question an hour ago.  Please do not post duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a screen shot of my emulator on a Mac.

1. Stupid question your pc does have enough ram and local storage right ??

**part1:**
[image: part 1]

**part2:**

[image: part 2]

2. What also helped was factory reset (too many test apps installed)

[image]

Comment: I have figured it out sorry for the troubles everybody, thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (not Xamarin forms, just Xamarin app in general)

After resetting the device in Android Device Manger I set the DataPartition via the GUI to 2GB.  Restarted the device but the dataPartition was still 200mb. (seen in the hardware-qemu.ini).

I noticed the Device Manager wrote to the config.ini the line

> disk.dataPartition.size=2 GB

So what I found worked for me was.

1. Factory Reset the device
2. Manually edit the config.ini to read 2000m not (not 2 G)

   > disk.dataPartition.size=2000m
3. Restart the device